# jQuery-cloned div not responding to click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clone

The goal is to expand a div to cover the whole screen without destroying the layout.

My current solution looks basically like this:

```
$( ".box" ).click(function() {
    copy = $(this).clone();
    copy.addClass("box-active");
    // save .box position + size     
    // maximize div
}

$( ".box-active" ).click(function() {
    // minimize div to saved .box position + size
    $(this).remove();
}
```

But the cloned divs will not respond to click events. Is there a way to work around that?

Full code: http://codepen.io/deuxtan/pen/oXQpRy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Event delegation** for dynamically created class in  DoM elements

```
$(".container").on('click', '.box-active', function() {
  if(isFullscreen){ 
    d.width = "100px";
    d.height = "100px";            
    d.top = 0;            
    d.left = 0; 

    $(this).animate(d, duration);
    isFullscreen = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: @Deuxtan - Glad it helps ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.on` for dynamically added elements.

```
$( ".container").on("click", ".box-active", function() {
    // ... minimize div ...
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue to use "clone", you need to include the "withDataAndEvents" boolean parameter in your call.  By default it is false.

So when you write it as

```
copy = $(this).clone();
```

you are allowing the default value of `false` to be passed, and no data or events is included in the close.  You need to explicitly pass `true`.

```
copy = $(this).clone(true);
```

[For reference, here is the documentation for the clone method.](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you did applied coick event on one element, when clonning it, you are not cloning it's events.

That is why you need to attach an event on all div's with class '.box-active'.

```
$('#parent-of-boxes').on('click', '.box-active', function() {
 ...
});
```

This will also work if you apply it on the docuemnt, but it's better to keet it minimalistic as possible, so add it to boxes parent block.

Using `on` function will apply it to all elements added to DOM that are inside `#parent-of-boxes`